# JAVA printwriter increase buffer size from 8192 bytes

Tags: java, buffer, printwriter

I'm trying to create a file that maps every possible binary combination of some part of speech tags, and for some reason the java program I've written just stops after 8192 bytes. I assume that this is the maximum buffer size or something? How can I change that?

My code:

```
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("S2.gr"));
        createS2(in, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error trying to open the files: " + e.getMessage());
    }


private static void createS2(Scanner in, PrintWriter out) {
    String[] pos = in.useDelimiter("\\A").next().split("\\n");
    out.println("1\tS2");
    for (String x : pos) {
        out.println("1\tS2\t_" + x);    
    }
    for (String x : pos) {
        String temp = ("1\t_" + x + "\t" + x);
        out.println(temp);
        for (String y : pos) {
            out.println(temp + " _" + y);
        }
    }
    for (String x : pos) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you flushing/closing the PrintWriter?  If you don't, then some of what you've written to the PrintWriter buffer may not appear in the file until it is flushed or closed.

Comment: buffer size just effects performance, not results.

Comment: Take a look at [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

Comment: Did you mean to write `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("S2.gr"), true);` ? The second argument in PrintWriter constructor can be either a boolean flag (for autoflush) or a String (for encoding).

Comment: Sorry, that second argument was me trying to set a maximum buffer size. That's not in my original working code. I'll fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    Scanner in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("S2.gr"));
        createS2(in, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error trying to open the files: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(in != null) in.close();
        if(out != null) out.close();
    }
```

Note: if you're using Java 7, there's a new feature to make this easier. e.g.

```
     try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("S2.gr")))
     {
        createS2(in, out);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error trying to open the files: " + e.getMessage());
     }
```

Note: I don't have a JDK 7 available to me at the moment, so the second example might not be 100% correct, but the idea is that the new language feature can manage closing resources for you.